# SSIS convert minutes to HH:MM with derived column

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to get a derived column that converts the sum of minutes to HH:MM. With the following expression I get the right result when the sum of minutes is less then 24 hours:

```
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,20)
  DATEADD(
    "minute",
    FIELDNAME,
    (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"01/01/2013 00:00:00"
  )
,12,5)
```

When the sum of minutes is more than 24 hours (1500mi)I want it to output like "25:00".

Is there a way to do this in a Derived Column Transformation?
Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Hours = minutes / 60

```
FIELDNAME / 60.00
```

Minutes = whats left over (modulo)

```
FIELDNAME % 60.00
```

So try

```
(DT_STR, 2, 1252) (FIELDNAME / 60.00) + ":" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) (FIELDNAME % 60.00)
```

Comment: Thank you, i managed to apply this solution in the query for the dataset.

Comment: Actually that is what I would normally suggest. Perhaps you could post your solution and help anyone who comes across this and is looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used this one:

```
Right("00" +(DT_STR,2,1252)(FIELDNAME / 60),2) + Right("00" + (DT_STR,2,1252)(FIELDNAME % 60), 2)
```